# Utilisation des subjonctifs imparfait et plus-que-parfait

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif

Le subjonctif imparfait et le subjonctif plus-que-parfait, sont-ils encore employés dans la langue française actuelle?

Je sais que dans la littérature avant le XXème siècle, ils étaient très utilisés. Mais de nos jours?

Comment: Très peu de chance d'en trouver dans un SMS!

Comment: Why was I taken 2 reputation points from this question? What did I do this time? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: indoxica: I don't know for sure. But let me add this remark because one word could be the reason of it all :-) The phrase “la langue courante” in French means “everday language”. If you meant “current” then the word is “actuelle” :-) This would include recent litterature works and the answer is then less obvious!

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez So I was taken 2 reputation points because of a word? That is sick! What do you think you are? The Gulag?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter…

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Just to be clear: I did not necessarily mean you; I meant you as in _vous_. Downvoting for such a trifling matter as a word seems to me to be pretty dictatorial. Besides, whoever did downvote my question (which happened more than once) should have given his/her reason for doing so. _The simple downvoting of questions is abusive and off-putting (to say the least) unless a logical and pertinent justification is being offered_. This site is just a learning community, not a police state. Some moderators (downvoters), whoever they may be, seem to have forgotten what they are.

Comment: A trifling matter that changes the question entirely. If “courante” was indeed not intended you should fix it. Nobody realized that it was not intended. Besides, downvotes are comunity feedback, not moderation. What you think is the purpose of this site is probably not what what everyone think it is. It requires some time to understand how the SE model works and even more time to understand why it works this way.

Comment: @indoxica Downvoting is part of the system as much as upvoting is. If you hover over the downvote button, the tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and that is most likely the reason it was downvoted, but as much as explanations are nice and encouraged, they are not mandatory. Also please do not take downvotes personally, we've all received them on our questions or answers for reasons known and unknown.

Comment: @indoxica Actually, this question did not cost you 2, it gave you 18 (and it receives answers). This proves this question is mostly perceived as valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non, les deux sont désuets. S'ils sont peut-être parfois encore utilisés dans la littérature et les textes officiels, ils ont disparu de la langue orale, en France en tout cas.

[Subjonctif imparfait](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_imparfait_en_fran%C3%A7ais) sur Wikipedia :

> Dans la langue contemporaine, [le subjonctif imparfait] s'apparente de plus en plus à une forme archaïque.

[Subjonctif plus-que-parfait](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_plus-que-parfait) sur Wikipedia :

> Le subjonctif plus-que-parfait n'est guère utilisé de nos jours que dans des discours formels ou littéraires.

Comment: And what have they been replaced with in contemporary French? (Sorry, I don't know how to say this in French...)

Comment: @indoxica Le subjonctif présent et le subjonctif passé (composé).

Comment: Petit parenthèse : on retrouve du subjonctif imparfait... dans une chanson de rap, de NTM en plus ! [Pour un nouveau massacre](http://www.paroles2chansons.com/paroles-ntm/paroles-pour-un-nouveau-massacre.html) : _"Que vouliez-vous que je fisse sinon du hardcore."_ Mais l'usage reste très marginal.

Answer (score 0):

Hélas, le français s'est châtré de modes et de temps très utiles et logiquement justifiés.

Paresse et laisser-aller coupables, complexification sous couleur de simplification.

Pour ma part, j'utilise, même à l'oral, passé simple et imparfait du subjonctif, et ne me permets de faute, à regret, que devant des interlocuteurs insuffisamment lettrés qui ne comprendraient pas.

**Voyez l'espagnol** : ils ont tout gardé, et tout un chacun est capable de comprendre, d'utiliser des tournures qui ne peuvent plus s'exprimer que pesamment en français.

La conjugaison y est restée logique, claire, donc en fait bien plus simple (orthogonale comme l'on dit en mathématiques).

Comment: C'est ton droit. Mais ça ne répond pas à la question.

Comment: @Evpok: la première phrase si, un peu. Tu réponds au troisième paragraphe, qui, je pense aussi, est de trop. Si la réponse à la question qui a été posée était moins lapidaire, je n'aurais rien contre l'ajout d'un avis personel, de préference clairement identifié comme tel.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La première phrase, oui, si on connaît déjà la réponse. Sinon j'ai des doutes.